# Relative velocity is not the simple difference of individual velocities?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

[image]

consider the case when car B was moving vertically up, not in the circular fashion. The relative velocity of A wrt B then would be Va-Vb wouldn't it?

why is it that when car be starts moving in the circle, the relative velocity of A wrt B decreases by the value wXr?

Comment: We have MathJax running on the site. That gives us LaTeX-alike markup for math. Using `V_A` inside single dollar signs renders as $V_A$. `\times`; renders as the cross-product $\times$; `\hat{j}` renders as $\hat{j}$; `\frac{15}{200}` renders as $\frac{15}{200}$,  `\mathbf{r}` renders as $\mathbf{r}$; and `\omega` renders as $\omega$. Use double dollar signs to get block set equations.

Comment: i'll remember those codes, didn't know about them till now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you have written is valid in both cases:
$$\vec {V_{\text{rel}}}=\vec V_A-\vec V_B-\vec{\omega} \times \vec r$$
When car $B$ is moving on a straight line (vertically), the radius of curvature of its path approaches infinity and so its angular velocity approaches zero ($\omega =\frac{v}{\rho}$). Thus, for the case that car $B$ is moving on a straight line; we have $\vec{\omega} \times \vec r=\vec 0$.

Comment: so i should take the formula for relative velocity as the one you've written in your answer and that will change according to the situation isn't it?

Comment: @lucas what does w* r signifies ?  And if both cars were moving in circles with different w then how will this formula work?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be including $\bf{\omega}\times\bf{r}$ at all. $\bf{\omega}\times\bf{r}$ should simply work out to be $15 \bf{\hat j}$, which you've already included!

Comment: the 15j which i have included at the start is the velocity of car B at that instant :) you should check lucas' answer, he's explained it!

Comment: What, then, does the $\bf{\omega} \times \bf {r} $ represent?

Comment: Sakazuki Akainu has indeed explained how $\vec {\omega} \times \vec {r} $ comes to zero for motion in a straight line, but why should it EVER be included as an extra term in the relative velocity equation?